# Create Glyphicon file with only two icons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I only use two icons from the entire set of Glyphicon font (included in Bootstrap).

They are used on a third-party js library that I don't want to mess with.

Yet, for it to work fine I have to download about 215KB just because of those two icons.

If I go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and customize it. I can create a much smaller file by selecting only the parts I use. However, as for Glyphicons, the option is to have All icons or none.

Does anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could upload it to [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) and pick them out. It can then generate a set of font files (wot, eot, svg, tff) for you. Its a pretty good interface.

Or if you're just using the .svg, you could possibly pop it open and edit it by hand. A lot of svg file format is surprisingly easy to parse mentally.

Comment: It worked! Thanks @Eric N! I had however to make some changes on the class names. Instead of keeping original font class names, icomoon generates some of his own rather than keep "glyphicon" class names. So one needs to do two things: 1. Before downloading, change icon names to glyphicon equivalents. 2. Download files. 3. Edit Styles.css file, deleting "icon-" from the beginning of each icon class name and replacing [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] for [class^="glyphicon-"], [class*=" glyphicon-"]